# Override value of magento order grid column

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, order-grid

I want to show only first name in bill to and ship to magento order grid.

**app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Resource/Order.php**

```
/**
     * Init virtual grid records for entity
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order
     */
    protected function _initVirtualGridColumns()
    {
        parent::_initVirtualGridColumns();
        $adapter       = $this->getReadConnection();
        $ifnullFirst   = $adapter->getIfNullSql('{{table}}.firstname', $adapter->quote(''));
        $ifnullMiddle  = $adapter->getIfNullSql('{{table}}.middlename', $adapter->quote(''));
        $ifnullLast    = $adapter->getIfNullSql('{{table}}.lastname', $adapter->quote(''));
        $concatAddress = $adapter->getConcatSql(array(
            $ifnullFirst,
            $adapter->quote(' '),
            $ifnullMiddle,
            $adapter->quote(' '),
            $ifnullLast
        ));
        $this->addVirtualGridColumn(
                'billing_name',
                'sales/order_address',
                array('billing_address_id' => 'entity_id'),
                $concatAddress
            )
            ->addVirtualGridColumn(
                'shipping_name',
                'sales/order_address',
                 array('shipping_address_id' => 'entity_id'),
                 $concatAddress
            );

        return $this;
    }
```

I tried with this function but no change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move Order Grid core file to local folder first

**app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php** 
to 
**app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php**

change **_prepareCollection** function as below

```
protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
         $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
         $collection->getSelect()->join(
            array('billing' => $resource->getTableName('sales/order_address')),
            'main_table.entity_id = billing.parent_id',
            array('billing_firstname' => 'firstname')
        )->where("billing.address_type =  'billing'");

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

replace below column code

```
$this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
       'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
       'index' => 'billing_name',
));
```

replace with below

```
$this->addColumn('billing_firstname', array(
    'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
    'index' => 'billing_firstname',
));
```